# Why do git branching diagrams not track branches "correctly"?

Tags: git

The screenshot below is taken from SourceTree.  I created a simple git repo with a few commits in it.  For each commit, the comment says what branch I was on when I made the commit.

[image: An arguably suboptimal commit diagram]

As you can see, the tree diagram is (arguably) suboptimal in that the commits to master are not all the same color, nor are they in a single lane.  Why is this?

(The tree diagrams drawn by GitHub and BitBucket seem to suffer from similar problems, so it's not just SourceTree.)

Obviously it doesn't much matter in this simple example, but in some of my projects we use a variant of git-flow, and it's often difficult to keep track of each of the git-flow "swimlanes" when you look at the tree diagram.  In part, this is because the tree diagram doesn't keep each swimlane the same color over time.

My suspicion is that the tree diagram is (arguably) suboptimal because the git repo doesn't actually contain enough information to draw the tree diagram the way I want it.  In particular, when two commits are children of a common commit (e.g. when you branch), git doesn't know whether the parent commit is "on the same branch" as child 1 or child 2.  Or, put another way, it doesn't know which child was the branch, and which was a continuation of the trunk.  Do I have this right?

Comment: The commits to master _are_ all in a single lane: the lane that changes from blue to purple at commit 94f458e. As to why they're a different colour, that's a question for the source code more than Stack Overflow. Maybe the developer chose to consider the path to the chronologically latest commit as the unbranching path? Submit a feature request to have it changed based on name of path.

Comment: When I said "lane", I meant it as "column".  And what I would like is if all the commits to master were in a single column, and the ones to release were in another column.  I mean, if you gave a human the DAG, the branch pointers, and the commit columns, they probably wouldn't draw the tree diagram the way it is drawn above.

Comment: While it's true git doesn't *require* users to provide enough information to draw the dag with correct swimlanes, a better drawing can be deduced in many cases by using commit messages as hints.  For example, merge messages typically start "Merge branch 'B' into A"; in such cases, it's clear what the names of the two source branches should be for swimlane purposes.  Users can easily add even more clarity; for example, whenever I create a branch, I put an initial empty commit in it "Create branch 'B' from 'A'". The graph drawing programs could do a *much* better job of taking such hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have alluded to, this is simply the nature of Git: A git commit does not contain any information about what branch the user was on when the commit was made.  (And this information cannot be reliably inferred from the information that git does maintain, which of course includes the DAG.)  This was a design choice made by the git authors.  Mercurial, in contrast, *does* store a branch name with each commit.  Git advocates argue that this is a bad thing, because it discourages the creation of possibly-temporary branches to try things out, and furthermore branch name collisions can easily arise.  See, for instance, [The Differences Between Mercurial and Git](http://www.rockstarprogrammer.org/post/2008/apr/06/differences-between-mercurial-and-git/).

Mercurial advocates argue that storing the branch name with each commit is a good thing, because it makes it easier to maintain an interpretable history.  That Mercurial stores a branch name with each commit seems to be the central reason why the author of [Why I Like Mercurial More Than Git](http://jhw.dreamwidth.org/1868.html) prefers Mercurial over Git.

Comment: Mercurial stores the branch name in each commit, if one uses Mercurial's named branches. Alternatively one can work with Mercurial's bookmarks, if git-like behavior is wanted.

Answer (score 3):

In git "branches" are implemented as pointer to a changeset.

It means, that a particular changeset may "belong" to several branches simultaneously.

That said - it is resolved in runtime and after you delete a branch (or modify your graph in any other way) - you cannot tell what branch it was committed to originally.

In your case the `94f458e` changeset does belong to both `master` and `release` so graph is perfectly correct.

Comment: It sounds like you're basically agreeing with what I wrote in the last paragraph of the question.  Except that you don't see git's current behavior as being less-useful-than-it-could-hypothetically-be.  On that, I would disagree: I can imagine a hypothetical VCS that keeps information that git currently throws away, and I can imagine that information being useful in some settings.  Like, for instance, this one.

Comment: Sorry if I sound disagreeable.  I really do appreciate you taking the time to answer the question!

Comment: @Adam L. Taylor: well, git does not track the info what branch the changeset was committed to. Mercurial does.

Comment: Ahhh.  Thanks, I didn't know that about Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Commits aren't "on" branches.  Branches are nothing more than local handy names for commits that interest you.  What matters is the structure of the history in your repo.  Focus on that. Commits `94f` and `18d` are both part of both branches' history, they're ancestors of both of the commits `release` and `master` refer to.

If your utility had drawn `master` on the left, its commit would have been drawn in blue and all the ones unique to `release`'s ancestry would have been magenta.

This is more or less what @zerkms said (and I upvoted his), just from a different point of view.

Comment: "If your utility had drawn master on the left, its commit would have been drawn in blue and all the ones unique to release's ancestry would have been magenta."  Yes, that's exactly how I would like it to be drawn.  And it seems like arguably a design flaw in git that it does not maintain enough information to draw the tree the way I'd like it to be drawn.

Comment: It turns out that you can gain quite a bit by losing the notion that "branch" is some kind of heavyweight abstraction, instead seeing branch names as nothing more than movable labels on the commit graph in your repository.  Commits themselves are just commits.